# pm 2 log Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, digital-ocean, pm2, ubuntu-server

```
  if I run 
  pm2 start bin/www.js      
  and 
  pm2 log
  |www      |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
  0|www      |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require 
  (/home/sadeeq/.nvm/versions/node/v15.4.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the- 
  middle/index.js:80:39)
  0|www      |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
  0|www      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/controllers/user.controller.js:1:16)
  0|www      | Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0
  0|www      |     at new Sequelize 
  (/var/www/html/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:281:13)
  0|www      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/models/index.js:6:19)
  0|www      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
  0|www      |     at Object.Module._extensions..js 
  (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
  0|www      |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
  0|www      |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
  0|www      |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
  0|www      |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require 
  (/home/sadeeq/.nvm/versions/node/v15.4.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the- 
  middle/index.js:80:39)
  0|www      |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
 0|www      |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/controllers/user.controller.js:1:16)
```

In my usercontroller.js line one I import my models folder.
in the sequelize connection i imported the dialect as mysql from .env

Comment: `const models = require('../models/index');` the first line of user.controller

Comment: `const connection = require('./config');
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');

const model = require('./models');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connection.db, connection.user, connection.password, {
    host:connection.host,
    dialect:connection.dialect,
    port: connection.port
});

const db ={};`  index.js file

Comment: `DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=*****
DB_DATABASE=*******
DB_DIALECT=mysql` .env

Comment: `require('dotenv').config()
module.exports = {
    db: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    dialect:process.env.DB_DIALECT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    port:process.env.DB_PORT
}` config.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pm2 ecosystem.config

```
 pm2 init
```

modify it to your project credentials

```
module.exports = {
   apps : [{
   name: "app",
   script: "./app.js",
   env: {
     NODE_ENV: "development",
   },
 env_production: {
  NODE_ENV: "production",
  }
 }]
}
```

In your package.json, modify your start script like the following:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
  }
}
```

Deploy your app